# Why does my code give me "list object is not callable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new to python and I've looked up a little bit of info and i cant't find the problem with my code, please help.

Code:

```
array = []
print ('Enter values in array: ')
for i in range(0,5):
    n = input("value: ")
    array.append(n)
a = input("Enter search term: ")
for i in range(len(array)):
    found = False
    while found == False :
        if a == array(i):
            found = True
            position = i
        else :
            found = False
print("Your search term is in position " + position)
```

Error:  at `if a == array(i)` line it says

> list object is not callable

Comment: *i cant't find the problem with my code* nether can we if you won't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: to access elements inside a list using index you should use `array[index]` not `array(i)`

Comment: @Guy well at the if a == array(i) line it says list object is not callable

Comment: It should be `array[i]`. And you probably want to cast `position` to string in the print. Also, using a nested loop is not the way to do a liner search, you are doing O(n^2) (if not an infinite loop). If it's not homework specifically asking you to implement it just do `if a in array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's generally hard to help without knowing what the error is, it's obvious here:

```
array(i)
```

is function call syntax, but `list`s aren't callable – you'll want subscript syntax:

```
array[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not have to run a while loop again while travering the array

```
array = []
print ('Enter values in array: ')
for i in range(0,5):
    n = input("value: ")
    array.append(n)
a = input("Enter search term: ")
for i in range(len(array)):
    if a == array[i]:
        position = i
if position:
    print("Your search term is in position " + str(position))
else:
    print('Not Found')
```

Here try this.

Also List/Dict can be accesed as list[i] not list(i)